# Unable to access json array data

Tags: json, react-native

i am trying to access data from a Json file but i can not retrive data from level 2.

let me paste my json here.

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "bookings": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "customer_id": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    "message": "Current booking list"
}
```

i want to access id from within bookings but i only can get data of success and message by doing `jsonresponse.success` is returns "true" but when i do `jsonresponse.data.bookings.id` it gives error. please help

Comment: You’re completely ignoring the array you mentioned in the title of the question!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jsonresponse.data.bookings` is an Array, so if you need to read id of first element you should use `jsonresponse.data.bookings[0].id`